# Python : how to use retry() on a function , it should retry until that function returns True

Tags: python

I'm trying to use retry but it's not retrying.

```
retry(stop_max_attempt_number=8,
      wait_fixed=15000)(check_type(var1,type))
```

check_type : this function will return either true or false. 
             It should retry until this function returns true.
             please help to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide more details. Which module are you using? What is happening that is not working out for you? Is retry your own function?

Comment: Where is `retry` defined? I can imagine it being something that returns a function that takes a function and its arguments as *separate* arguments: `retry(...)(check_type, var1, type)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're asking about `retry` function from `retrying` package. `retry()` will retry your function if it raises and exception, or if an assert fails, so you can wrap your function into another function like this:

```
def wrap_function(var1, type):
    return_value = check_type(var1, type)
    assert return_value is True

caller = retry(stop_max_attempt_number=8, wait_fixed=15000)(
    wrap_function)
caller(var1, type)
```

Also note that `retry()` must receive the function to execute, and it returns a function that you can call. So you must drop the parenthesis and arguments when you pass the function to `retry()` (otherwise you will be passing `True` or `False`) and you must save the returned function in order to call it later (I used variable `caller` in my example).